# How to add a fixed header to a QScrollArea?

Tags: python, header, pyqt, pyside, qscrollarea

I currently have a QScrollArea defined by:

```
self.results_grid_scrollarea = QScrollArea()
self.results_grid_widget = QWidget()
self.results_grid_layout = QGridLayout()
self.results_grid_layout.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetMinAndMaxSize)
self.results_grid_widget.setLayout(self.results_grid_layout)
self.results_grid_scrollarea.setWidgetResizable(True)
self.results_grid_scrollarea.setWidget(self.results_grid_widget)
self.results_grid_scrollarea.setViewportMargins(0,20,0,0)
```

which sits quite happily nested within other layouts/widgets, resizes as expected, etc.

To provide headings for the grid columns, I'm using another QGridLayout positioned directly above the scroll area - this works... but looks a little odd, even when styled appropriately, especially when the on-demand (vertical) scrollbar appears or disappears as needed and the headers no longer line up correctly with the grid columns.  It's an aesthetic thing I know... but I'm kinda picky ;)

Other widgets are added/removed to the `self.results_grid_layout` programatically elsewhere.  The last line above I've just recently added as I thought it would be easy to use the created margin area, the [docs](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.7/qabstractscrollarea.html#setViewportMargins) for setViewportMargins state:

> > > Sets margins around the scrolling area. This is useful for applications such as spreadsheets with "locked" rows and columns. The marginal space is is left blank; **put widgets in the unused area.**

But I cannot for the life of me work out how to actually achieve this, and either my GoogleFu has deserted me today, or there's little information/examples out there on how to actually achieve this.

My head is telling me I can assign just one widget, controlled by a layout (containing any number of other widgets) to the scrollarea - as I have done.  If I add say a QHeaderview for example to row 0 of the gridlayout, it will just appear below the viewport's margin and scroll with the rest of the layout?  Or am I missing something and just can't see the wood for the trees?

I'm just learning Python/Qt, so any help, pointers and/or examples (preferably with Python but not essential) would be appreciated!

---

Edit: Having followed the advice given so far (I think), I came up with the following little test program to try things out:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(640, 480)

        self.container_widget = QWidget()
        self.container_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.container_widget.setLayout(self.container_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.container_widget)

        self.info_label = QLabel(
            "Here you can see the problem.... I hope!\n"
            "Once the window is resized everything behaves itself.")
        self.info_label.setWordWrap(True)

        self.headings_widget = QWidget()
        self.headings_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.headings_widget.setLayout(self.headings_layout)
        self.headings_layout.setContentsMargins(1,1,0,0)

        self.heading_label1 = QLabel("Column 1")
        self.heading_label1.setContentsMargins(16,0,0,0)
        self.heading_label2 = QLabel("Col 2")
        self.heading_label2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.heading_label2.setMaximumWidth(65)
        self.heading_label3 = QLabel("Column 3")
        self.heading_label3.setContentsMargins(8,0,0,0)
        self.headings_layout.addWidget(self.heading_label1,0,0)
        self.headings_layout.addWidget(self.heading_label2,0,1)
        self.headings_layout.addWidget(self.heading_label3,0,2)
        self.headings_widget.setStyleSheet(
            "background: green; border-bottom: 1px solid black;" )

        self.grid_scrollarea = QScrollArea()
        self.grid_widget = QWidget()
        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.grid_layout.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetMinAndMaxSize)
        self.grid_widget.setLayout(self.grid_layout)
        self.grid_scrollarea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.grid_scrollarea.setWidget(self.grid_widget)
        self.grid_scrollarea.setViewportMargins(0,30,0,0)
        self.headings_widget.setParent(self.grid_scrollarea)
        ### Add some linedits to the scrollarea just to test
        rows_to_add = 10
        ## Setting the above to a value greater than will fit in the initial
        ## window will cause the lineedits added below to display correctly,
        ## however - using the 10 above, the lineedits do not expand to fill
        ## the scrollarea's width until you resize the window horizontally.
        ## What's the best way to fix this odd initial behaviour?
        for i in range(rows_to_add):
            col1 = QLineEdit()
            col2 = QLineEdit()
            col2.setMaximumWidth(65)
            col3 = QLineEdit()
            row = self.grid_layout.rowCount()
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(col1,row,0)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(col2,row,1)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(col3,row,2)
        ### Define Results group to hold the above sections
        self.test_group = QGroupBox("Results")
        self.test_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.test_group.setLayout(self.test_layout)
        self.test_layout.addWidget(self.info_label)
        self.test_layout.addWidget(self.grid_scrollarea)
        ### Add everything to the main layout
        self.container_layout.addWidget(self.test_group)


    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        scrollarea_vpsize = self.grid_scrollarea.viewport().size()
        scrollarea_visible_size = self.grid_scrollarea.rect()
        desired_width = scrollarea_vpsize.width()
        desired_height = scrollarea_visible_size.height()
        desired_height =  desired_height - scrollarea_vpsize.height()
        new_geom = QRect(0,0,desired_width+1,desired_height-1)
        self.headings_widget.setGeometry(new_geom)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Is something along these lines the method to which you were pointing?  Everything works as expected as is exactly what I was after, except for some odd initial behaviour before the window is resized by the user, once it is resized everything lines up and is fine.
I'm probably over-thinking again or at least overlooking something... any thoughts?

Comment: On your test program: commenting out the `grid_layout.setSizeConstraint` line, seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I'm sure I'll be able to work out the remaining minor issues myself (header initial widths mainly).  Your help has been greatly appreciated and have accepted your original answer as it led me down the right track.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be over-thinking things slightly.

All you need to do is use the geometry of the scrollarea's viewport and the current margins to calculate the geometry of any widgets you want to place in the margins.

The geometry of these widgets would also need to be updated in the `resizeEvent` of the scrollarea.

If you look at the source code for `QTableView`, I think you'll find it uses this method to manage its header-views (or something very similar).

**EDIT**

To deal with the minor resizing problems in your test case, I would advise you to read the [Coordinates](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qrect.html#coordinates) section in the docs for `QRect` (in particular, the third paragraph onwards).

I was able to get more accurate resizing by rewriting your test case like this:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(640, 480)
        self.container_widget = QWidget()
        self.container_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.container_widget.setLayout(self.container_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.container_widget)
        self.grid_scrollarea = ScrollArea(self)
        self.test_group = QGroupBox("Results")
        self.test_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.test_group.setLayout(self.test_layout)
        self.test_layout.addWidget(self.grid_scrollarea)
        self.container_layout.addWidget(self.test_group)

class ScrollArea(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QScrollArea.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid_widget = QWidget()
        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.grid_widget.setLayout(self.grid_layout)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.setWidget(self.grid_widget)
        # save the margin values
        self.margins = QMargins(0, 30, 0, 0)
        self.setViewportMargins(self.margins)
        self.headings_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.headings_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.headings_widget.setLayout(self.headings_layout)
        self.headings_layout.setContentsMargins(1,1,0,0)
        self.heading_label1 = QLabel("Column 1")
        self.heading_label1.setContentsMargins(16,0,0,0)
        self.heading_label2 = QLabel("Col 2")
        self.heading_label2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.heading_label2.setMaximumWidth(65)
        self.heading_label3 = QLabel("Column 3")
        self.heading_label3.setContentsMargins(8,0,0,0)
        self.headings_layout.addWidget(self.heading_label1,0,0)
        self.headings_layout.addWidget(self.heading_label2,0,1)
        self.headings_layout.addWidget(self.heading_label3,0,2)
        self.headings_widget.setStyleSheet(
            "background: green; border-bottom: 1px solid black;" )
        rows_to_add = 10
        for i in range(rows_to_add):
            col1 = QLineEdit()
            col2 = QLineEdit()
            col2.setMaximumWidth(65)
            col3 = QLineEdit()
            row = self.grid_layout.rowCount()
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(col1,row,0)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(col2,row,1)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(col3,row,2)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        rect = self.viewport().geometry()
        self.headings_widget.setGeometry(
            rect.x(), rect.y() - self.margins.top(),
            rect.width() - 1, self.margins.top())
        QScrollArea.resizeEvent(self, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ahh, interesting, thanks.  Ok, I can work out how to get the geometry, margins and do the calculations needed to get the required size and positioning, along with updating these. So I don't need to use the layout's addWidget method to include the header widget, and can just create it, set the geometry, and use setParent to make it also a child of the layout to ensure it's destroyed along with the grid when it's no longer needed?  I did take a look at the QTableView source, line [1282](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/gui/itemviews/qtableview.cpp#line1282) - I know very little C++

Comment: @DazGreen. The header should not be part of any layout at all. So just make it a child of the `grid_widget`. The `QTableView` source I was referring to is in the [`updateGeometries`](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/gui/itemviews/qtableview.cpp#line2033) method - which hopefully you should find a _lot_ easier to understand.

Comment: Excellent.  As soon as I'm able, and back on my development machine, I give this a whirl and post back (also upvote and accept this answer if it pans out for me and I've got the rep by then).  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have added some runnable sample code testing out what you were saying.

Comment: @DazGreen. Sorry for the delay in responding properly. See my updated answer for some refinements to your test case.

Comment: No problem, just glad to be getting any help at all - especially as this is all quite new to me still. I see what I did now - I re-implemented the MainWindow's `resizeEvent` rather than subclassing `QScrollArea` and doing it there!  And it also makes sense to move the header setup into the subclass too of course.  Apologies for perhaps not doing enough research, and/or being too dense to get it from the outset, your help has been invaluable.

Comment: I couldn't get horizontal scrolling to work in this solution. Setting the geometry doesn't respect the scrollarea's view into the scrolled contents. It works well when there is no scrolling though.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and solved it a little differently. Instead of using one [QScrollArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html) I use two and forward a movement of the lower scroll area to the top one. What the code below does is

1. It creates two QScrollArea widgets in a QVBoxLayout.
2. It disables the visibility of the scroll bars of the top QScrollArea and assigns it a fixed height.
3. Using the [valueChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractslider.html#value-prop) signal of the horizontal scroll bar of the lower QScrollArea it is possible to "forward" the horizontal scroll bar value from the lower QScrollArea to the top one resulting a fixed header at the top of the window.

---

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        vLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        widget.setLayout(vLayout)

        # TOP
        scrollAreaTop = QScrollArea()
        scrollAreaTop.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scrollAreaTop.setFixedHeight(30)
        scrollAreaTop.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        scrollAreaTop.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        scrollAreaTop.setWidget(QLabel(" ".join([str(i) for i in range(100)])))

        # BOTTOM
        scrollAreaBottom = QScrollArea()
        scrollAreaBottom.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scrollAreaBottom.setWidget(QLabel("\n".join([" ".join([str(i) for i in range(100)]) for _ in range(10)])))
        scrollAreaBottom.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(lambda value: scrollAreaTop.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(value))

        vLayout.addWidget(scrollAreaTop)
        vLayout.addWidget(scrollAreaBottom)
```

[image: Window resulting from above code.]

Comment: I chose this answer because the one with the margin trick doesn't work when the scrollarea contents needs to be scrolled horizontally. This works perfectly.